# Show whole taxonomy tree starting from current term

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to show taxonomy tree starting from current term. 
Like this when you are in taxonomy term1 page.

> -term1 (this is the term1 page where we are now)
>   --term2
>   --term3
>   ---term4
>   ----term5
>   ----term6
>   -----term7
>   -----term8

And if we are for example term4 page then it will show starting from term4:

> ---term4
>   ----term5
>   ----term6
>   -----term7
>   -----term8

I have used [Views Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) to but I have not found proper way to "filter" to show right terms when you are for example in term4 page.

All I can get is to show first child level like:

> --term1
>   ---term2
>   ---term3

It should show whole tree starting from current term - as deep as the tree goes.

Comment: Have you tried Views Tree module? https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree

Comment: @tunic Please read my whole question. I mention there that I have used Views tree, but could not figure out how to show right terms.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I miss that part. I tend to detect module names by its capitalized name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Taxonomy Menu Block Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_block)

> Taxonomy Menu Block allows you to make blocks containing unordered
>   lists that represent the structure of your vocabularies, creating a
>   menu out of your taxonomies (without using Drupal's menu system).

Comment: Thank you! Very nice! This module did the trick. In Taxonomy Menu block module I did settings: "Select a parent option" to Dynamic parent and "Select a parent level" to Follow active item. Now it shows exactly like I needed it to show.

Comment: Glad it helped.